# How to import a .jar in a Java's file without IDE and with Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I can't compile the files directly. I use `mvn package`.
I can't run the files directly. I use storm (Apache).
I don't know much about Maven.
I tried to just put the .jar in the same folder as the code and use `import com.path.of.jar`. It did compile, but when I tried to run, gave a NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: You need to tell Maven to add the JAR file to your classpath

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to add dependencies directly, like this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>sample</groupId>
<artifactId>com.sample</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you work on a maven based project, you manage dependencies through the `pom.xml` file at the root of the project. POM stands for Project Object Model and contains information about the project and configuration details used by Maven to build the project ([Introduction to the POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)).
A maven project produces an artifact uniquely identified by its coordinates: The `<groupId>`, `<artifactId>` and `<version>` that you normally find at the top of your `pom.xml` file. Once an artifact is published to a repository other maven projects can depend on it.

If you look at the content of your POM file you should see a `<dependencies>` element containing all dependencies that your project needs. If you want to import classes from a jar in your code you will need to find the maven coordinates of this jar (for example on [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/) or [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/)).

Once you have the coordinates add a corresponding dependency section. It should look like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Next time you run `mvn package`, the jar will be downloaded, used during compilation and packaged with your artifact.

And if you would like to get a good understanding of maven the following free book is excellent: [Maven: The Complete Reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/index.html)